SFMC Journey Builder Exclusion Script with Code Snippet
I wish to use an Exclusion Script within an Email Activity to check whether a contact should be suppressed from receiving an email.
Exclusion Script: TreatAsContent(ContentBlockbyId("123456")) > 0
Code Snippet (123456):
SET @ID = AttributeValue("ID")
SET @SendDate = NOW()
SET @count = ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("IDsToBeExcludedFromSends","ID", @ID))
IF @count > 0 THEN
InsertDE("IDsSuppressed", "ID", @ID, "SuppressedDate", @SendDate)
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@count)=%%

What it does: Checks if ID exists in DE: IDsToBeExcludedFromSends, if so, suppress it from sending as well as to add a row in DE: IDsSuppressed to indicate the ID which was suppressed and the datetime it occurred.
Problem: The exclusion worked as expected, however the InsertDE doesn't. I have tried InsertData as well.
Bonus: I wanted to also insert the JourneyName and ActivityName into the IDsSuppressed DE so that I know at which exact Journey and Activity this ID got excluded so I can follow up with a manual send in the future if required. However, I can't figure out how, seems like there are no official documentation to obtain Journey details using AMPScripts. Appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you!
Update: I ended up going the roundabout way of using NotSent tracking extract and join 3-4 data views to achieve the end result.

This due to the how 'Insert operations for the entire send are processed at the completion of the send'... this is specific to InsertDE() ... read more here

Does the DE: "IDsSuppressed" have a primary key? If so you should try to use the UpserDE() function instead, i.e., UpsertDE("IDsSuppressed", 1, "ID", @ID, "SuppressedDate", @SendDate)
Another thought:
Do you send a test send or a real send to test this? According to the official order of processing, insert operations for the entire send are processed at the completion of the send.
